# What does "that's too fine" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I commented on Stack Overflow, and someone replied "[that's too fine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20086490/c-compare-read-in-float-to-zero/20087558?noredirect=1#comment29940742_20087558)" to me.

What does this sentence mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears like they were *trying* to say "that is fine too" or, in other words, "that is also an acceptable way of doing it".

If they really meant "that's too fine" (which I really doubt), it would mean something like:

- that way of doing it is too satisfactory

That is just nonsensical. It is most likely a typo or a non-native English speaker. Looking at their other answers/comments, it would appear they are from a non-Enligh speaking country. See this other example:

> where the brackets are needed

That is out of order, and should be: "where are the brackets needed?" That isn't the kind of mistake a lazy native speaker would make.

In a very different context, it could be understood as a compliment. But that is only for urban slang, and it only refers to attractiveness of another person (or body part).

> That booty is *too* fine.

I feel embarrassed just typing that, but I figured you should know it could be said. That is definitely not what that user was trying to say though. That's just some trivia.

Comment: Note "fine" may mean "flimsy"/"fragile" too. "That's too fine. I need something crude and sturdy" would be a normal usage.

Comment: @SF. That's too fine. ;) But seriously, I don't think that is what the user meant. I wouldn't refer to well-written code as "fine"... I'd only use it for something that is like hair/thread.

Answer (score 0):

In an engineering discussion, "that's too fine" would refer to something like the thread pitch of a screw or a surface finish which can be defined as too fine for the purpose and thus unnecessarily expensive. In the context of that original post, I would too say he/she mean "that's also fine".

Comment: This actually does work as an answer, not a comment. With a bit more rep, [you will be able to post comments](//ell.stackexchange.com/privileges/comment). Until then, please do not use answers as a workaround. They will usually be deleted, and that makes more work for the site moderation.

Comment: Boarderline an answer, hence I try to go for a comment :-) EDIT: Christ almighty! I now realize this is a three year old thread which showed up in the right-hand side hotlist. Rookie mistake.

Comment: We don't care about "thread necromancy" here either. Age doesn't matter much.

Comment: @NathanTuggy Oh! Over at EE.SE you will be rosted for it.

Comment: I raised it from the dead because I'm trying to kill a tag :) Any question that only has one answer is fair game for a second one in my opinion, and it's never a bad thing to look over old questions and see if we can improve the question or answer.